# Does the Upstream Feeds feature cause Billing to increase as a side effect?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

Our organization currently has an artifact feed per Team Project. We also have an organization-level feed that has our Team Project feeds set as upstream, as it makes the configuration of NuGet for various repositories in our organization much easier. If I have a package `Foo` in feed `MyTeamProjectFeed`, and that package is 2MB, but then I access it from feed `MyOrganizationFeed` which has `MyTeamProjectFeed` set as upstream, will I be billed for the 2MB of the original package (in `MyTeamProjectFeed`), or 4MB for the original package, plus the package that becomes cached (in `MyOrganizationFeed`)?

Comment: For now, upstream feeds will generate additional billing.If you want to avoid extra billing, you can try to disable upstream feeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, each copy of a package in Azure Artifacts counts towards your billing meter.